# Unable to configure wifi and/or bluetooth on Google Glass EE 2

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, google-glass

I have a Google Glass *Enterprise Edition 2* (yes). I am unable to connect either wifi or bluetooth (primary goal is wifi).

For wifi, I first tried the following:

1. On the glass: Settings → Wifi → Selected network.
2. On the MyGlass web site: "Continue with my computer" → Enter wifi info → Generate QR code.
3. Glass prompts to scan QR code, I scan it, it says "invalid QR code". Considerable searching yielded no additional troubleshooting info.

I then attempted to use the MyGlass app on an Android device. I tried the following on a Google Pixel and a Kyocera DuraForce Pro:

1. Install MyGlass app.
2. Enable bluetooth.
3. There aren't really any on-screen instructions; it appears there is supposed to be an embedded video tutorial in the app but it never loads. Clicked "find my glass" in the app. It did not see the Glass.

I tried pairing the Glass with the phones manually, first from the Glass side:

1. Enter Bluetooth settings on phone so it becomes visible.
2. Phone shows up on Glass, select it, pair.
3. Pairing appeared successful, but then it immediately disconnects.

Then I forgot all devices and tried again from the phone side:

1. Enter Bluetooth settings on Glass so it becomes visible.
2. "Google Glass Enterprise Edition 2" shows up on phone. Select it, pair.
3. Pairing appeared successful, but then it immediately disconnects.

In both cases, after pairing, if I select the Glass from the phone's Bluetooth menu it says "Connecting..." → "Connected" → immediately disconnects.

In all cases, I was unable to make any progress in the MyGlass app.

So I am unable to configure wifi, and unable to pair the device. Does anybody know how to do either of these?

Answer (score 2):

All right, well I was able to configure wifi at least. I had to use the Android menus rather than the QR Code based UI:

1. I found an application called Vysor that allows control of the Glass through a PC, so I installed it, connected the Glass with a USB cable and did the rest through there.
2. From there I went to the device information card, clicked it 5 times (there's a countdown) to open the Android menus.
3. I then went to wifi configuration and entered the configuration there just as on any other Android device, and it connected just fine.

Still no luck with Bluetooth, but since my use for Bluetooth was just to configure wifi in the absence of working QR codes, and I was able to configure Wifi through the Android menus via Vysor, I don't really have a use for Bluetooth any more.